# ngbCollapse collapse not working for multiple divs which are dynamic in one page

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

ngbCollapse dynamically generating in main for loop which checks for Sun in json obj, if sun not there then gives an option to Add_Sun(). As it is in a loop it gives every row to add_sun. when clicking on 'Add Sun' button isCollapsed[i] collapse divs are opened and for closing vice versa. Is there a way to specify the collapse just for one single div opens and closes with respect to index? I have no control over mainarray. Please suggest.

```
    --------------component TypeScript-----------------

        export class MyComponent {
            public isCollapsed: boolean [] = [];
        }


    -----------------component HTML----------------
 <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of mainarray; let i= index">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let pdict of obj | keyvalue">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let pdictEle of pdict.value | keyvalue">

    <ng-container *ngIf="chkforSun(pdict.value)">

    <ng-container *ngIf="pdictEle.key =='Sun'">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="isCollapsed[i] =! isCollapsed[i]" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed[i]" aria-controls="collapseForm" ng-model="isCollapsed">Add_Sun</button>

        <div id="collapseForm" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed[i]">
        <div class="table-container">
        <table style="width:100%">
        <tr><td align="left" width="50%"><label>Add Sun: </label></td>
        ............Some code to add items .........
        </tr></table>
    <label><button class="text-right"type="button"class="btn btn-info" (click)="add_sun(value)">Submit</button></label>
    <label><button class="text-left" type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="isCollapsed = true">Cancel</button></label>
         </div>
         </div>
        </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!..

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let obj of mainarray; let i= index">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let pdict of obj | keyvalue">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let pdictEle of pdict.value | keyvalue">
     <ng-container *ngIf="chkforSun(pdict.value)">

    <ng-container *ngIf="pdictEle.key =='Sun'">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="[pdict.key =! pdict.key]" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed[i]" aria-controls="collapseForm" ng-model="isCollapsed">Add_Sun</button>

        <div id="collapseForm" [ngbCollapse]="pdict.key">
        <div class="table-container">
        <table style="width:100%">
        <tr><td align="left" width="50%"><label>Add Sun: </label></td>
        ............Some code to add items .........
        </tr></table>
    <label><button class="text-right"type="button"class="btn btn-info" (click)="add_sun(value)">Submit</button></label>
    <label><button class="text-left" type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="isCollapsed = true">Cancel</button></label>
         </div>
         </div>
        </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```